# android - do I need to request permissions for Intent.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Tags: android, android-intent

- I developed my app with targetSDK 22 / Android - 5.1
- However, with api level 23, I need to implement request permissions.
- In android docs, I read that if I use Intent, then I dont need to request permissions.

I have following code

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Do I need to explicitly `requestPermissions` for the above use case?

I get error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
```

Comment: No That does not need permission. Are you facing any issue?

Answer (score 0):

OK..I resolved I had to do few things to make it work as I was using api 23

- http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/camera/photobasics.html
- I had to enable Camera front and back in emulator setup